# How to close popup that contains Vaadin iframe

Tags: java, javascript, vaadin

I have a Vaadin application that will be use in a popup (with iframe including) into a web page. I have to close this popup directly from Vaadin application.

So, I will try this method without success :

I have a jquery modal window that include my app with an iframe :

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <iframe style="border: 0px;" src="http://localhost:8080/vaadin-app"
      width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

In my app, I have a button with this listener :

```
@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
   if (event.getSource().equals(close)) {
        // Close the iframe from this point
    }
}
```

I don't really know what I have to do. I try to call window.parent with this :

```
JavaScript.getCurrent().execute("console.log(window.parent);");
```

But I got undefined in my js console. So I can't get the element #dialog or other method to close the popup.

Can you give me some tricks or link to do what I went ?

Regards

Comment: is this cross domain?